# loading xml from specific folder inside document folder

Tags: ios, swift, xml

i hope you are all healthy and well. 
i am trying to load an xml file that i previsiouly saved in a folder inside the document folder of the ios app. but i havent managed yet to load it. i have done the same with xml files that are saved by default within the bundle and it works. any ideas?

```swift
public func loadXML(filename: String) {
    var parser : XMLParser?
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "xml") {

        parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        parser!.delegate = self
        if parser!.parse() ?? false {

        } else {
            print("Unable to parse")
        }

    } else {
        print("File read error")
    }
}
```

here is the method i have used to save the xml file before i am loading it:

```swift
func saveXML(filename: String, foldername: String) {

    var post = "some xml stuff"

    let filepath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("/" + foldername + "/" + filename + ".xml")

    do {
        try post.write(to: filepath, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

        print("saved.")
    } catch {
        print("failed to write file")

    }
}
```

`Bundle.main.path(forResource: filename, ofType: "xml")`

is not the right way to get the right path for my xml file. i have saved my xml-file inside a folder in the document folder which i have done by the saveXML()-function.
to get the right path for saving i used this line: 
`getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("/" + foldername + "/" + filename + ".xml")`

the `getDocumentsDirectory()` - method gives back this:

```
FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
```

and now i have to do the same the other way around. but i havent found a solution

Comment: Please explain what exactly is not working. "i havent managed yet to load it" is not very clear.

Comment: i added my comment to the question with proper formatting. thanks for the reminder @koen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you know what the `filePath` is from your write method:

```
let filepathURL = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("/" + foldername + "/" + filename + ".xml")
```

Then you can parse your file as follows:

```
guard let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: filePathURL) else {
    print("cannot read xml file")
}
parser.delegate = self
...
```

Comment: thanks. i am almost there.. i just get this error: "Cannot convert value of type 'URL' to expected argument type 'String' when i try the String-method

Comment: @VladMedicus Glad it helped! Please consider accepting my answer.

Comment: i have posted an answer. not sure if thats the right way @koen

Comment: @VladMedicus it's recommended to write a new question

Comment: done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60726371/loading-xml-error-thread-1-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrappin

Answer (score 0):

thats the final method:

```
func loadXML(filename: String, foldername: String)
{
    let filepath = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(foldername + "/" + filename + ".xml")

    let filePath = filepath.absoluteString
    guard let parser = XMLParser(contentsOf: filepath)
        else {
            print("cannot read xml file")
            return
    }

    parser.delegate = self
    if parser.parse() ?? false {

    }else {
        print("Unable to parse")
    }
}
```